# Why the infinitive in "Je te remercie pour m'aider"?

Tags: infinitif, noms

> Je te remercie pour m'aider. = I thank you for helping me.

I don't understand why *aider* is in the infinitive. Shouldn't it be “Je te remercie pour m'**aide**”?

Comment: Where did you get that sentence please? [I] Thank you for helping me would be: Je te remercie de m'avoir aidé. The English uses a gerund and the French uses a past infinitive.

Comment: @Lambie > technically it will depend if you helped in the past or are currently helping. If currently helping, it could be "Merci de m'aider".

Comment: Ou bien c'est présent: Je te remercie de m'aider. [présent, sens, futur, l'aide n'a pas encore eu lieu] Ou bien, c'est passé: Je te remercie de m'avoir aidé. Pourtant, ma question reste la même: Where did you get that sentence?

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty arises from the fact that both of

**Remercier quelqu’un pour quelque chose / Remercier quelqu’un de quelque chose**

are correct BUT they are not used in the same cases (according to two celebrated French dictionaries).

(See http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/merci-a3754913)

> Remercier quelqu’un **de** + nom abstrait (aide, gentillesse, amabilité,
> accueil, etc.) (abstract noun)
>
> Remercier quelqu’un **pour** + nom concret (cadeau, objet, fleurs, etc.)
> (concrete noun)

However, the usage does not make any difference between concret and abstract nouns. Counter-examples appear even in the texts of famous French authors, let alone colloquial language.

Therefore, nowadays, one may use both of

> Je vous remercie de/pour votre réponse

accordingly.

Attention : Only **de** can be used with an infinitive.

Thus,

> Je vous remercie de m'aider. Thank you for helping me.
>
> Je vous remercie de m’avoir aidé(e). Thank you for having helped me.
>
> Je vous remercie de/pour votre aide. Thank you for your help.
>
> Je vous remercie de me répondre. Thank you for answering me.
>
> Je vous remercie de m'avoir répondu(e). Thank you for having answered me.

**EDIT**

Voir aussi les commentaires qui suit la réponse (@jlliagre et @aCOSwt)

Comment: *Je vous remercie de votre réponse* ;-)

Comment: Au debout j'avais écris Je vous remercie pour votre réponse. Je crois tous les deux sont corrects, n'est-ce pas ? J'ai modifié la réponse car dans la réponse je parle des noms abstraits et concrets. Si j'ai fait une faute je vais le corriger.

Comment: Les deux se disent. http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1012 *Remercier pour* était très rare jusqu'au XXe siècle. Il s'est ensuite répandu, peut être sous l'influence de l'anglais. .

Comment: Alors le " ;-) " voulait dire quoi ici ? Ma réponse est correcte, n'est-ce pas ? Que dois-je y rajouter ?

Comment: Le ";-)" était un vrai clin d’œil et montrait par un contre-exemple que la réponse était trop catégorique. S'il est correct de dire que seul *remercier de* est possible avec un infinitif, l'usage n'est pas aussi tranché dans les autres cas.

Comment: Alors (et désolé de te déranger:-)!) hormis le cas de l'infinitif on ne peut bien distinguer l'emploi de **de et pour** pour les noms abstraits/concrets comme j'affirme ?

Comment: C'est l'opinion de l'OQLF et je la partage. Voir aussi http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/merci-a3754913 et http://www.laculturegenerale.com/remercier-de-remercier-pour-accueil/

Comment: @jlliagre : non non! Il n'est pas *"correct de dire que seul remercier de est possible avec un infinitif* dans la mesure où il est fréquent avec un infinitif passé avec l'auxiliaire avoir : *Remercier **pour avoir** + pp*. Encore un coup d'actif / passif sans doute.

Comment: @aCOSwt Tu dipilectomes ;-) je parlais d'infinitif présent. D'autre part, "fréquent" est peut-être un peu exagéré, mais il est vrai que *remercier pour avoir +pp* existe bien, même si on peut ne pas schtoumpfer la tournure...

Comment: Pour que ta réponse soit plus pertinente j'aurais ajouté le nom associé au verbe, par exemple *pour l'aide* /  *de m'aider*.

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence doesn't make sense in French because it would be understood as:

> In order to help myself, I thank you.

*Remercier pour* is possible when referring to a thing :

> *Je te remercie **pour** les chocolats.*

With a verb, an idiomatic sentence would be :

> *Je te remercie **de** m'**aider***.

Here the infinitive is used (to help).

If you want to use the noun *aide* (the help), you can use either of these forms:

> *Je te remercie **pour** l'**aide** que tu m'as apportée.*
>
> *Je te remercie **de** l'**aide** que tu m'as apportée.*

The latter is slightly more formal.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is definitively not correct.
I would add to the other responses that both following sentences sounds correct to me:

> Je te remercie pour ton aide
>
> Je te remercie de ton aide

Answer (score 1):

The other answers rightly pointed out that it was not a proper sentence. However, distracted by the improperness of the sentence, they have not answered the actual question as to why it's the infinitive.

To the matter at hand

> I don't understand why aider is in the infinitive. Shouldn't it be “Je te remercie pour m'aide”?

In other words, why is it **helping** (the gerund acting like a noun) in English and why **aider** (the infinitive) in French.

Well, that's just the way it is. As a French person, I could also ask why English use the gerund like that. I happened to read the [gerund entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) on Wikipedia and I stumbled upon

> [...] This is not a normal use for a Latin gerund. Moreover, the clause may function within a sentence as subject or object, which is impossible for a Latin gerund.  [...] Latin never uses the gerund in this way, **since the infinitive is available**.

And there you have your answer. Bottom line is gerund used for verbs acting like a noun is the infinitive in French.

A few examples

> Fumer est interdit.
>
> Smoking is not allowed/forbidden.
>
> I look forward to meeting you.
>
> J'ai hâte de te rencontrer.

I realised there was something not right about the latter example. I wanted to draw a parallel between French and English but **avoir hâte de** is always followed by a verb. The expression is **avoir hâte de faire quelque chose**. So we cannot use a noun whereas **I look forward to** is expecting a noun hence the gerund. **I look forward to your answer**. I've often seen **se réjouir de** for **to look forward to** but the latter is feeling happy and excited about something **that is going to happen** whereas the former is missing this component (at least, all definitions I've seen don't say anything about something that is going to happen). However, **se réjouir de** can be followed by a noun, so it might be a better fit, at least to support what I'm saying.

> Je me réjouis de notre partenariat.
>
> I look forward to our partnership
>
> Je me réjouis de travailler avec vous
>
> I look forward to working with you

And one for the road

> (Playing videogames) can be dangerous. () -> the whole thing act as a noun
>
> Jouer aux jeux vidéos peut être dangereux.

German takes it a step farther

> Das Rauchen (article + infinitive + uppercase)